# Objective C webservice (with php server) using SUDZC

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, web-services, ios5

I'm using sudzc for my webservice in objectcive-c. Server-side is based on PHP. I've got defined php array in my WSDL as ArrayOfstring. When sudcz SoapRequest getting a response from server there is valid XML. But when is called method on instance of sudzc generated class ArrayOfString initWithNode:element, (element is CXMLElement type), nothing happens. And the instance of generated ArrayOfstring is empty. When I NSLog(instance of ArrayOfstring) it print's just surrounding text <ArrayOfstring><ArrayOfstring> and nohting is in it. Or when I call [Soap deserialize:element] in the string ouptpu I can see just last element of returned xml set. Have someone got any Suggestions to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, dude.. It does not allow to initialize that objects just by passing the "normal" fields such as int or NSArray or like..
but if you want to see the actual result, check request.receivedData, which is NSData, you need to convert it into NSString, then it is in pure xml format, now you need to parse the xml and fetch the result you need.

The major problem is that the handler method's (id) does not give anything. more over, if I want to initialize a field (of service-created type), firstly, I have to create cxmldoc, then cxmlelement,then cxmlnode, which in turn can be initizlized to the respected object.